# Best approach/model to match keywords to sentences

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm very new to machine learning and AI stuff. I have the following problem I want to tackle and would like some advice as to how I should approach it:

Basically, I want to take some keywords and produce a sentence or list of sentences where the keywords are most relevant: `[]string -> []string`.

The keywords could be any word, e.g. cat, dog, lemon, tea. and they would return a set of sentences that have been learned before.

So for example:

```
dog -> its a nice day
cat -> its not a nice day
lemon -> its a normal day
tea -> hello, world!
```

Would be a very basic data set. And then I would enter the keywords `[ dog, tea ]` and be given back `[ "it's a nice day", "hello, world!" ]`. In addition I would want to be able to train this model with new words and sentences.

At first glance I thought I could use a naive bayesian classifier? Though the model requires learning, and to my limited understanding of ML, I figure this would be some kind of neural network classifier.

Some research leads to me that NN are only capable of dealing with floating point/integer inputs? So I would have to map the strings somehow to this. Which is apparently called a "sequence to sequence" model.

Is this the way I would approach this problem? A sequence-to-sequence neural network? Or am I completely off the ball here.

Comment: Sorry, your problem is not clear: 1) what do you call "keyword" exactly? in your example the "keyword" doesn't have any relation with the sentence. 2) can you have several sentences for one keyword then? 3) what do you want to learn with ML, what is your input data?